@InsertOnlyProperty on Entity (not-embedded)
I noticed that the @InsertOnlyProperty (and I assume the @ReadOnlyProperty annotations) don't apply to properties that are Entities.  Is there a reason this isn't implemented?
Having a look at the WritingContext class, it would seem that it wouldn't be difficult to filter on isInsertOnly and isReadOnly as required.
Is there a reason this feature couldn't be added, or is there another way to do this?

There is no specific reason for this not being implemented.
You can submit a PR to implement it.
